# Why Does One JavaScript Function Work Here But Not The Other?

Tags: javascript

Encountered this small puzzle, and do not understand enough about JavaScript internals to
see the reason for the behaviour.  It isn't holding up my work, but I would appreciate it if
someone could cast some light on it.

> ```
> function SetVarWrapsMMxCalled(){
>     var EstTrigValTHALISTx1=289437562937;
>     var BIGDiv = document.getElementById("nested");
>     nested.textContent = EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
>     return EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
> }
> ```

```
function easierThen(){
    var howEasy=88;
    return howEasy;
}

var EverSoEasy = SetVarWrapsMMxCalled(); // Does not work
var EverSoEasy = easierThen();           // This DOES work  ???!

function seriously(EverSoEasy){
    var omgsosilly=EverSoEasy;
    var nestedDiv = document.getElementById("nested");
    nestedDiv.textContent = omgsosilly;
}
```

For those for whom I failed to make the question clear enough, I am not using both of
these 2 lines at once:

```
var EverSoEasy = SetVarWrapsMMxCalled(); // Does not work
var EverSoEasy = easierThen();           // This DOES work  ???!
```

The point was that one line, the second, produces a value displayed in the div as would
be expected, but the first one does not.

Explored the thing quite a lot more, and it seems, as can be seen from
[toying with the code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/MountainMan72/9wskN/) that the problem was not what I had thought it was.

Now I have a new question.  Great.  But it is a long weekend.  Later.

Comment: Is `SetVarWrapsMMxCalled()` defined in a different (temporary) context than `easierThen()`?

Comment: You're reusing and redefining variables. The variables and functions are named badly. Poorly written code is hard to debug. You're creating your own problems here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a javascript error because the variable `nested` is not defined:

```
function SetVarWrapsMMxCalled(){
    var EstTrigValTHALISTx1=289437562937;
    var BIGDiv = document.getElementById("nested");
    nested.textContent = EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
    return EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
}
```

It probably should be this:

```
function SetVarWrapsMMxCalled(){
    var EstTrigValTHALISTx1=289437562937;
    var BIGDiv = document.getElementById("nested");
    BIGDiv.textContent = EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
    return EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
}
```

In the future, look in your browser's error console or the debugger console and it will tell you which line has the first javascript error.  This should not be a mystery.  When somethnig isn't working, that is the first place I look.  There should be no errors in your code showing in the console.

---

FYI, this could be simplified too like this:

```
function SetVarWrapsMMxCalled(){
    var EstTrigValTHALISTx1 = 289437562937;
    document.getElementById("nested").textContent = EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
    return EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
}
```

Comment: When somethnig isn't working, that is the first place I look.

Comment: Hmmm. But the *undefined* the inspector shows while clearly important, is not instructive.  Hence sites such as S.O. where somebody who has some knowledge of JavaScript might know precisely WHY the *undefined* is popping up, yeah?

Comment: @MountainMan - I guess you do need to know that a value of `undefined` means the variable has never been assigned a value (e.g. doesn't exist).

Comment: @MountainMan - do you see that in the line `nested.textContent = EstTrigValTHALISTx1;`, there is NO variable named `nested`.  Thus `nested` is `undefined` and thus has no property called `.textContent` which causes an error when you try to reference it.

Comment: @correcting that however, was not enough to address the problem causing the code to fall over.  The issue was that the *SetVarWrapsMMxCalled* was setting textContent and then *seriously(EverSoEasy)* was trying to set it again.  Not sure why that was a problem.  Calling the function more directly avoids it.  Happy July 1st!

Comment: @MountainMan - just so you realize, you didn't provide any code that called `seriously()` or describe that as any part of your problem so there's no way we could know that was part of your problem.  Isn't this the best possible answer you could have received given the info you provided? Getting complete answers requires providing the relevant information to the problem.  You defined the problem as `var EverSoEasy = SetVarWrapsMMxCalled();` didn't work to which we provided an answer.  The other problems you have were not part of this question.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  But I guess that in your early going you encountered problems and as you wrestled with them discovered there was more to them.  One of the challenges is trying to describe things when one is possessing spotty knowledge.  In any case, you have been supportive and direct.  Thanks.

Comment: @MountainMan - yes, it is challenging to include all the relevant info when you don't really know what the problem is.  I was just pointing out that when you do finally understand the problem, you should consider the answers you got in light of the info you actually provided.  I thank you for doing that here.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
function SetVarWrapsMMxCalled()
{
    var EstTrigValTHALISTx1=289437562937;
    var BIGDiv = document.getElementById("nested");
    BIGDIv.textContent = EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
    return EstTrigValTHALISTx1;
}
```